# How to make fuzz testing for ASP.net projects

Tags: asp.net, security, testing, testcase, fuzzing

How can I do fuzz testing in my asp.net Project?
Any idea about fuzz testing & where is it used?

Answer (score 0):

[Fuzz testing](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fuzz_testing) is automated or partially automated tests and pushing a variety of different inputs to your application, i.e. your website.  Typically these would range from easy stress tests, i.e. if you utilise an 'if...else' statement you would test using inputs that force the true and false values.

In web terms there are packages that can help, but one I'm aware is [WatiN](http://watin.org/) that plugs into MS Testing, and it is free as well.  Although throwing / Paypalling some beer money is always a good karmic thing...